# Does Google Cloud's external application load balancer's weight based traffic splitting maintain user affinity?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

From the documentation here, https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/traffic-management-global#traffic_actions_weight-based_traffic_splitting, we see that we can assign percentage weights to split traffic. Deploying new versions is a listed use-case.

How exactly does traffic affinity work, both in the default, and configurable cases?

Is traffic split based on a weighted coin flip (I hope not)?

Could traffic be split on opaque cookies so that users can see consistent versions on refreshes?

If cookies might be disabled, are there other heuristics like IP to maintain affinity?

I tried Googling. Underlying affinity details were light.

I tried codesearching, and found this proto comment https://github.com/jackskj/terraform-pb/blob/f9cb58090c486b817f13abb7882fa2cd47b4f33e/terraform-provider-google/resources/google_compute_url_map.proto#L297-L303, but would like to confirm that this applies to external load balancer, and maybe not only to internal load balancers, etc

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: load balancer affinity by default is best-effort via IP. However, you can manually set an HTTP_COOKIE if you want user ID affinity. For example, if your user spans multiple platforms like mobile and web, their backends will not be consistent by default with IP affinity.

Q:

> How exactly does traffic affinity work, both in the default..

See https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#session_affinity.

A:

> By default, all Google Cloud load balancers select backends by using a five-tuple hash (--session-affinity=NONE), as follows:
>
> Packet's source IP address
> Packet's source port (if present in the packet's header)
> Packet's destination IP address
> Packet's destination port (if present in the packet's header)
> Packet's protocol

Q:

> .. and configurable cases?

See all of the options in the table here https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#bs-session-affinity

A:

> - None (NONE)
> - Client IP (CLIENT_IP)
> - Generated cookie (GENERATED_COOKIE)
> - Header field (HEADER_FIELD)
> - HTTP cookie (HTTP_COOKIE)